# Installation of Ubuntu 18.04 freezes on Acer Swift 3 (AMD Ryzen 5 + Radeon Vega 8)

Tags: boot, radeon, acer, distro-recommendation, amd-ryzen

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 on my new Acer Swift 3 (with default Win 10), but the installation freezes, both if I try the Live and if I try to install directly. I saw that this is a common problem for many linux users (not only using Ubuntu) and I really try all the suggested solutions. I set up the BIOS correctly, I tried other Ubuntu versions (16.04 and 19.10), other linux distro (Elementary OS), I tried to change the grub into nomodoset and to burn the iso image with fedora media writer. All that was unsuccessful.

My question is therefore: has anyone some updates and/or possible solutions for this issue? Do anyone know other linux distros which can maybe work? Does anyone know if the issue is being somehow solved and all I have to do is maybe waiting?

Thank you in advance, every help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I am running into the same problem with the same laptop. I couldn't fix the problem but I found [this linux.org thread on boot problems](https://www.linux.org/threads/boot-problems-with-ubuntu-boot-hangs.24385/). In particular this helped me to go through the installation:

> In the grub boot screen, press <kbd>e</kbd> and edit the line that has
>
> ```
> quiet splash
> ```
>
> and change that part to
>
> ```
> quiet splash nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=5500
> ```

However once I installed Ubuntu, it does not work properly (freezes after a while). But I though it may help you. In any case, if you find the solution please post it.
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for answering. Apparently there has been some problems of compatibility lately with ryzen 5 3000 and some Linux distros (see link). AMD released an update for the bios to be downloaded from the constructor's website (Acer in this case) that should solve the bug. I'll try to see if that fixes the issue and I'll let you know down here.

https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Ryzen-3000-BIOS-Update-Good